# excel sum the 25 highest numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have tried to find a formula that will look into the sheet1 colum D where there are allot of numbers. some friends and i are having a competition and we want to sum the points with the top 25 points for each contender.

if we use =SUM(Sheet1!D2:D10000)  then all the numbers are summed but wo only want the top 25 numbers. what formula to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LARGE` Formula, combined with `SUM`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(Sheet1!D2:D10000,ROW(INDIRECT("1:25"))))
```

If you are using Excel 2019 you can use the `SEQUENCE` function. It returns a sequence of numbers. We can use it to get the top N values and then sum them up.

Generic Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(range,SEQUENCE(num_values,,[start_num], [steps]))))
```

Comment: And I went with: "SUM(LARGE(A1:A40,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}))" but I like your use of indirect() here.

Comment: nice than you this works in Excel, i also tested it in Google drive excel and it works but when i add it to the created document i get an error instead. is it because we dont have 25 numbers in the colum?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the LARGE function.

```
=SUM(LARGE(D:D,1),LARGE(D:D,2),LARGE(D:D,3),LARGE(D:D,4)....
```

and so on

Or you create a separate table with `LARGE(D:D, ROW()-n)` where n is rownumber -1 the and then pull down (fill down) to get the 25 top and sum them.

Example:

Here I have 50 values and I placed my new table on row 4 so my formula is `LARGE(A:A,ROW()-3)` which results in the largest value.
Then I can just fill down the 25 values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with duplicates, try:

```
 =SUMIF(D2:D10000,">=" & LARGE(D2:D10000,25))
```

This will return an error if you have fewer than 25 entries.